# How to install Captcha::reCaptcha module?

Tags: perl, recaptcha, centos7

I'm trying to use Google's reCaptcha v2 system with a Perl script. I can find information on how to use the modules in places like
[`Captcha::reCAPTCHA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Captcha::reCAPTCHA)
and
[`Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2)
but the instructions on how to install the module are confusing.

I have `cpan` installed but I don't know the proper command to download and install the module. I'm running CentOS 7.

Can anybody walk me through what I need to do to get these libraries on my system?

Are these the same module/library?

Comment: The instructions are pretty clear. You need to describe what is confusing you, otherwise the best we can do is repeat what you have already read.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for V2. - I just tried a few commands and I think I figured it out.  there are a variety of different sets of instructions from different generations of the technology that contradict each other.

Comment: @Trent: *"there are a variety of different sets of instructions from different generations of the technology that contradict each other"* That isn't true. The `cpan` utility has behaved pretty much the same since its first non-alpha build in 1996, and the manual method of installing modules described in [`perlmodinstall`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html) has been static for much longer. Please give links to some of this variety of contradictory instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing cpan:

```
yum install cpan
```

Looks like this is the command that worked:

```
cpan Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2
```

Comment: Instructions for installing a module from 2001 should still be applicable. Please post a link. Your experience seems very odd, and your final solution is far from complex. Is is hard to imagine what variations on this were confusing you.